# Получить имя константы из #define

Tags: c++11

Можно ли получить имя константы, определенной в `#define`? Например, есть константа `#define DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR = 1`, можно ли получить по числу 1 строку `DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR`?

Comment: думаю нет) после компиляции дефайнов точно не будет

Comment: А почему бы не использовать enum-ы для этой цели например.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. На вход компилятора поступает код, где уже нет никаких макросов...

Кстати,

```
#define ODIN  1
#define ONE   1
#define EIN   1
```

Какое имя вы хотите получить? :)

Comment: ну мало ли) дефайн штука мутная. Может мы переопределим дефайн в какой-то макрос чтобы все названия в константах были, потом как-то достучимся...

Comment: @pavel И нарвемся на тот случай, о котором написал я выше - будет у вас десяток макросов, которые в 1 развернутся - и какой из них вернуть?...

Comment: все... списком...

Comment: для этого нужен clang и собственный парсер.